# Linux Mint 14 and wireless connection issue

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint

I have a Dell E1505 with Windows XP. I decided to install Linux Mint 14 to learn more about Linux as part of my programming job. So I downloaded Mint 14 (Cinnamon), installed it, and it works fine with the Ethernet connection. However, I am not able to connect via WiFi.

Can somebody please explain the steps needed to configure the wireless card driver (Broadcom 4311 chip)?

Answer (score 1):

Try do add more info about "But I am not able to connect to wireless".

Type in terminal

> ifconfig -a

If you see youre wireless chip (wlan$) everysing is OK and you need sometking like wicd or network-manager to connect to AP.

If there are no wlan iface in output, you need to install driver (e.g. compat-wireless).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1) Depending on your system download 32 or 64 bit package
from http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

2) Go to a terminal to the dir with package.

3) tar -xvzf hybrid-portsrc-.tar.gz 
Replace version with one you have

4) Install kernel headers (eg. in fedora “yum install kernel-headers”)

5) make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`

if There were no errors

6) Unload Modules from memory
rmmod ndiswrapper b43 ssb bcm43xx b43legacy

7) For WPA
modprobe ieee80211_crypt_tkip

8)Check if Compiled Module is working
insmod wl.ko

Now Probably a new interface will be there for wireless (wlan0 or eth-1)
To check it run
iwconfig
iwlist scanning

Making it load on boot

1)cp wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname-r`/kernel/net/wireless/

2)depmod -a

3)rmmod wl

4)modprobe wl

5)Add following Lines to /etc/rc.local (in openSuse /etc/rc/rc.d/boot.local)

modprobe wl

Answer (score 0):

Install the firmware:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After it's installed, reboot.

I tried everything else with no success. I did this and the wireless immediately came on with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You must install a Linux driver for your wireless card.

Before testing if your wireless has problems with the driver or not, follow these steps:

1. Reboot system
2. Go to the GRUB menu and press <kbd>E</kbd> for editing the kernel line
3. Insert `noapic acpi=off` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then see if your wireless is working